# How do I upload multiple images in specific folder in sitecore programmatically?

Tags: sitecore8

I am trying to upload large amount of images from file system into sitecore, inside a specific folder in media library. I am using Sitecore 8.1.3 version.

I have tried using MediaCreator.CreateFromFile(), MediaCreator.CreateItem(), MediaCreator.CreateFromStream() functions. Issue I am facing is while uploading images, I want all images in "XYZ" folder inside media library but instead "XYZ" folder is getting created again and again for each individual image.

so for lets say 200 images, 200 folders are getting created and inside each folder one image is getting uploaded.

it seems all three functions create the entire item path regardless of whether it already exists in media library or not.

here is how i am using it

```
MediaCreator creator = new MediaCreator();
fileLocation = C:\Images\temp.png
var options = new MediaCreatorOptions();
options.Destination = "/sitecore/media library/XYZ/temp";

Item newItem = creator.CreateFromFile(fileLocation, options);
```

it repeats for multiple images with different image names.

Comment: Can you check if the new `XYZ` folder is created, is it created in the same language which is used by the original `XYZ` folder?

Comment: If you just need to upload a whole bunch of media from your local computer and it doesn't need to be programmatically you can zip them up, or use the Media Upload Watcher and drop them into that folder instead: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/mass-uploading-media/

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment. But Richard Seal'answer on StackExchange is pretty much what you are looking for I think. : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15433/how-to-copy-multiple-items-to-a-new-location

You have 2 ways - if you can connect up Sitecore Rocks, that has an option to multi-select items and move them around in Visual Studio and rename etc...

The second option would be to use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE) to script that out. This example will give you a good starting place:

```
$rootOfitemsToMove = Get-Item “/sitecore/content/Location A/subfolder 4”;
$destinationItemPath = “/sitecore/content/Location B/subfolder 4”;

$templateNameToMatch = “My Template”;

Write-Host “Moving items from: ” $rootOfitemsToMove.Paths.FullPath ” to: ” $destinationItem.Paths.FullPath ” …”;

Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -match $templateNameToMatch } | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($name))
    {
        $newName = "$($name)0"  # Add some logic here to rename the folder
        $newPath = "$($destinationItemPath)/$($newName)"

        Move-Item -Path $_.ItemPath -Destination $newPath;
        Write-Host “Item moved to: $($newPath)“;
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host “Couldn’t move Item: ” $name;
    }
}

Write-Host “Moving items complete.”;
```

You would need to work out the logic of how the folders are renamed. Moving a parent folder should also move the child items with it.